# $LASTEXITCODE undefined after command

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm going crazy, can someone explain me why the value of $lastexitcode is undefined?

look to my simple attempt: if I launch command dir, I get the correct output so $LASTEXITCODE must be 0.

unfortunately, if I try:

```
$LASTEXITCODE
```

I haven't any return value.
it's the same situation if I give before an command like "diiiiir" or something similar that doesn't exist.

Comment: `dir` doesn't set `$lastexitcode`. Try something else. :) No idea why, but actual executables do (like `ping.exe`). Probably because internal commands don't "need" errorlevels.

Comment: Not finding the cmdlet, e.g. `diiiiir`, doesn't set $LASTEXITCODE either.

Comment: @bzlm `dir` is alias for `Get-ChildItem`. See `Get-Alias dir`. Because it is a PowerShell cmdlet, it will not set `$LASTEXITCODE
`. But running the `cmd /c dir`will, because then you execute the internal `dir command in cmd`, and not the PowerShell `Get-ChildItem`.

Answer (score 9):

$LASTEXITCODE is only set by executables or batch files when they return. PowerShell commands can be checked with $?. See [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130406014157/http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/05/12/powershell-error-handling-and-why-you-should-care.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

In particular `$LASTEXITCODE` is set by "Legacy" executables... it is equivalent to the old DOS/Windows `%ERRORLEVEL%` variable.  Here is the best way to manage `$LASTEXITCODE` within PowerShell:

```
cmd /c "exit 0" #Reset $LASTEXITCODE between runs while debugging
```

A batch (.bat)/command (.cmd) file will set it when called from PowerShell:

```
exit /b <exitcode>
```

For example, create a command file called SetLASTEXITCODE.cmd with the following line:

```
exit /b 2
```

Then, call the command file from PowerShell:

```
cmd /c "SetLASTEXITCODE.cmd"
```

Output should be:

```
exit /b 2
```

Now test `$LASTEXITCODE`:

```
$LASTEXITCODE
```

Output is:

```
2
```

Note: on so called "Legacy" executables (also includes the old .com files), if the developer/programmer did not set the ERRORLEVEL from whatever programming language the exe was written in (usually via an API call), then ERRORLEVEL/LASTEXITCODE will not be set!  I used to write these way back when in the early '80s and there was a distinction back then between [internal commands](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/71986) like your 'dir' example which does not set ERRORLEVEL and external commands in (.com) or exe files - a long since forgotten detail.

One last example... modify the command file to include the following and repeat above test... it sets both ERRORLEVEL within command file and exits with `%ERRORLEVEL%` setting `$LASTEXITCODE`...

```
cmd /c "exit /b 2"
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%
```

Have fun...

Comment: The "internal commands" link in this answer is now broken, and I'm having trouble finding an archived copy. The URL at one point redirected to https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/71986 - which in turn redirected to https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/71986/ms-dos-5.0-internal-and-external-commands - and the archived copies of *that* page appear okay at first, but then the text vanishes just a few seconds after they load!

Comment: The best suggestion I have for anyone trying to check the cited source is to go to https://web.archive.org/web/20170214130209/https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/71986/ms-dos-5.0-internal-and-external-commands and do a `Ctrl-A` `Ctrl-C` very quickly when the text appears. You can then paste it into a text editor. It does indeed confirm that `dir` is an internal command defined in command.com, distinct from external commands with their own .com/.exe/.bat files.